# Generate uniq username using first and last name in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I need to dynamically generate uniqe username during user's registartion.

Algorithm:

when user's full name is "John Doe" username should be "jdoe" (if available).
If not, it should generate jdoe1, jdoe2 and so until username will be available.

Any exisiting simple solution for this?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Please [post your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here.

Answer (score 9):

```
def generate_username(first_name,last_name):
    val = "{0}{1}".format(first_name[0],last_name).lower()
    x=0
    while True:
        if x == 0 and User.objects.filter(username=val).count() == 0:
            return val
        else:
            new_val = "{0}{1}".format(val,x)
            if User.objects.filter(username=new_val).count() == 0:
            return new_val
        x += 1
        if x > 1000000:
            raise Exception("Name is super popular!")
```